# Travelling on passport that has 1.5 months left

Tags: passports, pakistani-citizens, uk-residents, saudi-arabia, expired

I was supposed to get a new passport last week but it turns out they have delayed it for 1 month, while I booked tickets for next weekend.

I am travelling from the UK to Saudi Arabia with a layover in Turkiye on a Pakistani passport. The first airline is Turkish and then flyadeal. Will I be able to travel on my current passport, which expires in 1.5 months?

I am returning on 10 April, the expiry is on 1st May.

Edit: I have UK indefinite leave to remain.

Comment: Are you going to Pakistan? What is your status in the UK?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella I have a idefinate leave to remain. I will add it to the question and no I m not going to Pakistan, my destination is Saudia and overlay in Turkey

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you won't

TIMATIC (an airline's documentation database) states

> Saudi Arabia - Destination Passport
>
> Passport required.
>
> Document Validity
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry **must be valid for a minimum of 6 months** from the arrival date.

Comment: oh, is there any way I can travel on some temporary papers? It is consulate mistake which will cost me and my family mental stress

Comment: @localhost An emergency travel document (ETD) is usually a temporary document that enables you to get back home if you’re stuck abroad without your passport for some reason. As that’s not the case for you, I doubt you can do anything.

Comment: Enquire with the Pakistani consulate, they might, ot not, be able to issue you a 1-year temporary passport. I have no idea whether Pakistan allows this, but my own country does... Might as well check...

Comment: @localhost not consulate’s mistake. It is your mistake. You should renew passport asap when there is a trip coming. Don’t trust any government agency.

Comment: @vasin1987 I agree